The document.getElementById(elem) function does not work when called from JavaFx webEngine
My program loads a web page and tries to scroll to an element with given ID.
This is the scollInd(ID) Javascript function as defined and called by WebEngine:
    engine.executeScript(" function scrollInd(elem){\r\n"
+ "    const element = document.getElementById(elem);\r\n
+ "    if(element == null){\r\n"
+ "      return;\r\n"
+ "    }\r\n"
+ "    const topPos = lement.getBoundingClientRect().top;\r\n"
+ "    window.scroll({\r\n"
+ "      top: topPos,\r\n"
+ "      behavior: 'instant' \r\n"
+ "    });\r\n"
+ "  }"
+ "scrollInd(\"_addizione\");");    

It seems that the getElementById function does not find the searched element and returns null.
Note that if I insert the function into the html page and use a normal browser, everything works fine.
Where am I wrong?

Create and post a [mre]. (There are many possibilities for the behavior you observe. It is impossible to know why it is happening just from the snippet you posted.)

Off-topic: This would be easier to read and maintain using text blocks which have been available in Java for almost five years and are supported in major IDEs such as Idea.

My guess is you're inserting this code before the _addizione element. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element
